# Math - find which quarter of a screen has been touched

Tags: android, math, coordinates

From my android MotionEvent (touch event) I have the X and Y co-ordinates where the screen was touched (specifically, it's an ACTION_UP event, but whatever.)
From the last time OnSizeChanged was called, I have stored the current maximum X and Y values for my view object (basically the whole screen).

I want to find out whether the user touched the screen in the top, bottom, left, or right quarters of the View.

Of course, if I wanted top-left, top-right, bottom-left, and bottom-right quarters, this would be a lot easier; I'd be using a pair of nested if.. then.... else statements to check whether the touch X value is greater or less than half the maximum X, then do the same with Y and half the maximum Y.

But since I want up/down/left/right, the maths is a little trickier.
I know that since (0,0) is in the top left, I can check for whether (Maximum X divided by Touch X) is greater than (Maximum Y divided by Touch Y). This gives me top and right / bottom and left.
But I can't get my head around what I need to distinguish between top and left / bottom and right.

I had thought that a check for whether (Maximum X divided by Touch X) is greater than (Negative Maximum Y divided by (Maximum Y minus Touch Y)) should do it, but apparently not.

Any thoughts?

```
if (iMaxXSizeDpi / event.getX() > iMaxYSizeDpi / event.getY()) {
  Log.d(TAG, "Either bottom or left");
  if (iMaxXSizeDpi / event.getX() > -iMaxYSizeDpi / iMaxYSizeDpi-event.getY()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "This one");
  } else {
    Log.d(TAG, "That one");
  }
} else {
  Log.d(TAG, "Either top or right");
  if (iMaxXSizeDpi / event.getX() > -iMaxYSizeDpi / iMaxYSizeDpi-event.getY()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "This other one");
  } else {
    Log.d(TAG, "That other one");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is correct,

```
iMaxXSizeDpi / event.getX() > iMaxYSizeDpi / event.getY()
```

it is potentially dangerous. Division by 0 may occur. So, re-order the formula:

```
iMaxXSizeDpi * event.getY() > iMaxYSizeDpi * event.getX()
```

Now the other line. Let's denote the line with `f(x)`. Then, we know that:

```
f(0) = iMaxYSizeDpi
f(iMaxXSizeDpi) = 0
```

Solving this with the prototype `f(x) = a x + b` yields:

```
f(x) = -iMaxYSizeDpi / iMaxXSizeDpi * x + iMaxYSizeDpi
```

And your touch event is above that line iff

```
event.getY() < f(event.getX())
event.getY() < -iMaxYSizeDpi / iMaxXSizeDpi * event.getX() + iMaxYSizeDpi
```

This is the formula you need to plug into your if-cascade. Watch out for integer division if `iMaxYSizeDpi` and `iMaxXSizeDpi` are integers.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you @Nico.
Yes I had been aware of the divide-by-zero issue, but I'd figured that since the coordinates came from a touch event, which gives the median location and has a width > 0, it wouldn't be a problem. However I've altered my code as you suggest for best practice.
Also thank you for the warning about integer division - by simply implementing this code into mine without any typecasting it was always checking for event.getY() < (iMaxYSizeDpi)! It might have taken me a while to figure out what was going wrong there.